# CRUD in ASP.NET via XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How do I insert a line break into an XML file so that it will render correctly when pulled into a web page?

It's an ASP.NET Web Application using C#, and is intended for CRUD. For now I'm displaying the results in a GridView, although I intend to transition to something closer to HTML divs for formatting purposes.

I tried this - CDATA with a br tag.

```
<instructions>
  <![CDATA[Line One of the text <br />
  Line two of the text.]]>
</instructions>
```

However this is not producing the desired result. What am I doing incorrectly?

Edit to add: 
I did try /r/n (first); it quite literally showed up as /r/n. Tried the other tweaky code things like putting it in various escape enclosures, etc.

Encoding is utf-8.

Comment: Have you tried `\r\n`?

Comment: use "Environment.NewLine:

Comment: keep plain text in xml and use white-space: pre-line; in css

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past by replacing the character codes for the line breaks (I think they're `chr(10)` and `chr(13)`) with a `<br />` tag.